# How is it possible to see C# code after compilation/optimization?

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, compiler-construction, yield

I was reading about the `yield` keyword when I came across a sample chapter from **C# in Depth**: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter6/IteratorBlockImplementation.aspx.

The first block of code utilizes the `yield` keyword to make a simple iterator. But, the second block of code shows this code after the compiler has had its way with it. Among other things, it has exploded the `yield` statement into a state machine.

Several other examples of code being modified by the compiler is evident on the page.

**My question is:** Was the author actually able to access the code after compilation, or did he infer what it was going to look like?

Comment: Reflector is your friend

Comment: The real answer to this question should be "All too easily!"

Comment: Reflector really is your friend.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can have a look using Reflector, that's probably your best bet:

http://reflector.red-gate.com

Comment: Just downloaded it, thanks for the tip! Will the non-Pro version still integrate with VS?

Answer (score 9):

The author himself mentioned:

> Obviously the compiler doesn't actually produce C#, but I've used Reflector to decompile the code as C#.

in the same paragraph, titled **High level overview: what's the pattern?**

Comment: Wow. This is why skimming articles won't get you very far :). Thanks!

Comment: @SimpleCoder -- you need to be able to **see sharp** if you want to **C#**, my friend =).

Answer (score 4):

Probably both.  It's quite easy to reverse-engineer compiled assemblies using [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/).  And the C# language spec, which defines how various syntactic-sugary things are compiled, is a public document.  The author could have used either approach, or a mixture of the two.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [ildasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to take a look at the compiled IL.

(Really, it's good fun once you get your eye in)

Answer (score 2):

.NET CLR actually has a form of assembly called MSIL, along with an assembler and dissembler. So yes, you can actually compile the code, then see the exact compiled CLR instructions.

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020103545/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/080404-1.aspx

Answer (score 2):

**dotPeek** by JetBrains

https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/

It's free and easy to use :)